# SCORM 2004 3rd Edition Authoring Tool

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

I'm looking for an Authoring Tool that creates Content Packages based on SCORM 2004 3rd edition through the use of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I don't want to use Authoring Tools that use Flash to create Content Packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good list of e-learning authoring tools at http://elearningatlas.com/